# Genesys GVP 8.1.7 support for sql server 2012

Tags: genesys

Does Genesys GVP 8.1.7 support databases on SQL Server 2012 with or without compatibility mode?

Thank you
S Code

Comment: To be honest I would just contact the vendor directly

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the URL https://docs.genesys.com for full details - you'll need the Partner login access to view the page.

Specifically for GVP -
GVP 8.1.2+ supports SQL 2008, the latest releases are however of GVP 8.5.x which have also have support for SQL 2012 but NOT for SQL Server 2014.

MS SQL Server 2012 -> 8.5.1+

MS SQL Server 2008 -> 8.1.2+

A better approach will be to verify each solution's support and compatibility as some solutions of Genesys support 2012, 2014 (with cluster).

Answer (score -1):

GenesysLabs GVP 8 support MSSQL 2000 to 2016.
Programs Examples are included in the Genesys CustomerCare Comunity.
https://genesyspartner.force.com/customercare/GenesysCommunityLogin

All the code is Java, and throw java you could connect to all databases!